# Angular6 micro front-ends routing

Tags: micro-frontend

I have angular 6 **micro front end application**. It's having 4 different applications inside Main application. And how do i implement **routing** between those applications.And how do i implement routing in Main application (**i have many child routes in Main application**) and Sub applications too. I am using "@angular/elements".
Please find my code in this this repository ***https://github.com/nagaraju123/microfrontend***

Comment: Can you please show us some code so that we can reproduce your problem and help you solve it?

Comment: Can you please help me with some information i.e.,  How many ways to implement micro front end routing using "Angular6"

Comment: No, I mean in the actual question, put the code in the question by editing it.

Comment: You mean that Routing part or Entire Code

Comment: Whatever we need to solve your question, as much as we need.

Comment: Please find the Code here https://github.com/nagaraju123/microfrontend.git                 Thanks for your support

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Routing for a "true" microfrontend architecture should follow:

- Each microfrontend is a separate service in your infrastructure
- You have an ingress/reverse proxy in front of these services that allows routing to a specific service based on path
- You have a single domain name: `app.yoursite.com`
- You configure the ingress to route to the correct microfrontend based on path (e.g. `/namespace/accounting` goes to the accounting frontend)
- The microfrontends themselves control how they make requests (e.g. the accounting frontend serves some `accountingPage.js`, and code within that page will make all fetch requests with prefix: `/namespace/accounting`)

Summary:
It really depends on what you mean by "microfrontend" though. Often when people say microfrontend, they refer to creating separate JS bundles, but still sharing a single backend.

A "true" microfrontend architecture achieves total encapsulation of both the static assets/javascript and the backend/request handlers. Separation of concerns, not separation of technologies. Code served by one microfrontend is totally isolated from code served by another... stitched together by a common "platform" service.